# Exporting each frame from After Effects as a separate Photoshop file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, adobe-after-effects

The Adobe After Effects CC feature `Composition -> Save Frame As -> Photoshop Layers` does exactly what I want. However, it is very time consuming to do this for each  frame (I am animating a game character in Adobe After Effects, and then using the `.psd` files to create a sprite sheet).

Is there any way (perhaps a script) that can repeat this action for each frame, automatically numbering them, so it's one-click to export the entire sequence?

Answer (score 4):

1. Drag the composition into your <kbd>Render Queue</kbd>
2. Click on <kbd>Output Module</kbd>
3. From the first dropdown, select <kbd>Photoshop Sequence</kbd>
4. Render!

Answer (score 0):

In After Effects (or media encoder) you can select `PNG sequence` as a format option.